# How to configure not loading node relations even partly?

Tags: lazy-loading, fetch, spring-data-neo4j

I am using **Spring data Neo4j** project while my nodes contains relations properties using **@RelatedTo** , **@RelatedToVia** annotations, I don't want any of them to be fetched eagerly so these properties ain't marked with **@Fetch** annotations.

When node is fetched all his other relations are partly fetched ( each fetched related node only with id the rest of the properties are null) this happens in nested way also for the relations of the relations.

There is way to prevent this overhead? using include/exclude fields like in spring data mongo db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here to get a better understanding how the lazy/eager loading in Spring Data Neo4j works:
[lazy loading in spring data neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852491/lazy-eager-loading-fetching-in-neo4j-spring-data?rq=1)

But what you have to remember is that in general what you don't have marked with **@Fetch** annotation you have to get it yourself with `neo4jTemplate.fetch()`.
This means exactly what you found out by yourself, that if you **fetch** a property using **@RelatedTo** annotation, then you have to use **fetch** for **the properties of that property** using **@RelatedTo** annotation.

As far as I know there is no way you can use to avoid this.